# Windows Phone 8 Button Tint Color and Image

Tags: button, windows-phone-8

So I'm playing around with Windows Phone 8, thinking about porting our iOS app over to that platform and so I have all the assets I want to work with but one thing I couldn't figure out is if theres someway to change the tint color of an image. For example in iOS I could simply just do something like `[UIButton appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]` and then all the of the buttons will have a red tint over the image that I use. I'm just not sure if there's something like that for Windows Phone of if I need to update the assets for windows phone to have the exact tint color I want to use for this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish this in a few ways. One is to create a style that defines a red tint overlay for your button. In Visual Studio you create your button and right click on it (within the designer) and select Edit Template -> Edit a Copy...

When you do this you will get the default Style for a Button. Scroll down to where the Border element is which contains the ContentControl. A Border can only have one Child so you will need to wrap the ContentControl with a Grid. Under the ContentControl add another Grid and give it a Background of Red and a low Opacity so you can see through it.

Here is just the Border part of the style

```
    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        <Grid Background="Red" Opacity=".4"></Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Another way (and more advanced) is to create a custom control that would allow you to set a tint color on it. This solution is very similar to the one above and would use the same style but instead of setting the background to red as above the Background would bind (using TemplateBinding) to a DependencyProperty that is on your new control (which would derive from Button).